# Java Spring App - Download MySQL database on the cloud in a embedded database inside the app

Tags: java, mysql, spring, database, spring-boot

I have a dilemma, I have an application made in Spring Boot with JSwing that I use to display the information of a MySQL database in the cloud, my problem is that the hosting that has that database with its tables and relationships goes slow, then I had thought if it is possible to pass the MySQL database with its tables , relationships and data in a database embedded inside within the application and that the application is updated whenever there are any changes to the cloud database.

The embedded database should keep the data downloaded if the application is closed and if there are no changes to the cloud database it should not update anything.

What's the best alternative? Which database technology might be best for my problem?

Comment: Questions about database technology, such as replication, is probably better asked on https://dba.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @Andreas thanks you i'll take a look